# Select rows from table based on if serial is in multirange

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

### Problem

Given a table with a `BIGSERIAL` I want to query for the rows which have an index contained in a multirange passed as an argument.

The table, trimmed down, looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE event
(
    id         UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    index      BIGSERIAL   NOT NULL,
    data       JSONB
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON event (index);
```

What I naively want to is select those events which have an index in the multirange I pass as an argument:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    event
WHERE
    INDEX <@ $1;
```

The table is decently large (30mil rows) and the query is run often so it's essential that it runs quickly. The above query results in a `seq scan` which is quite slow, compared at least to our old "hack" described below.

Typically the multirange doesn't contain many ranges and generally has a infinite end for the last range, i.e. `{[100, 110], [160,]}`. Additionally, we usually query towards the end, so the values are typically in the range of 30 million. A query would usually return just a few hundred rows, rarely more.

### What I've tried

Our old solution handles this problem by in the backend-code splitting it up the multirange and doing a query for each range.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    event
WHERE
    INDEX >= LOWER($1) AND(UPPER_INF($1) OR INDEX < UPPER($1));
```

This results in an efficient index scan and takes a few milliseconds to complete. However, it's far from ideal especially because we also want to have `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` work for the entire multirange.

### Queries and analyze

Running the naive query above against production using a multirange fetching just a few events.

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, buffers)
SELECT
    id, index, data
FROM
    event
WHERE
    index <@ '{[30000000,30000005],[30000010,30000025)}'::int8multirange;
```

Gives the following:

```
Gather (cost=1000.00..1476747.50 rows=154593 width=157) (actual time=4326.117..5610.042 rows=21 loops=1)
Workers Planned: 2
Workers Launched: 2
Buffers: shared hit=1204253 read=95107
I/O Timings: read=9552.560
-> Parallel Seq Scan on event (cost=0.00..1460288.20 rows=64414 width=157) (actual time=5178.488..5605.465 rows=7 loops=3)
Filter: (index <@ '{[30000000,30000006),[30000010,30000025)}'::int8multirange)
Rows Removed by Filter: 10064869
Buffers: shared hit=1204253 read=95107
I/O Timings: read=9552.560
Planning Time: 0.066 ms
Execution Time: 5614.964 ms
```

And just as an example using `<@` with a `int8range` fetching almost the same data, just a few more rows:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, buffers)
SELECT
    id, index, data
FROM
    event
WHERE
    index <@ '[30000000,30000025)'::int8range;
```

Gives the following:

```
Gather (cost=1000.00..1476751.99 rows=154593 width=157) (actual time=2510.701..4249.822 rows=25 loops=1)
Workers Planned: 2
Workers Launched: 2
Buffers: shared hit=1236553 read=62777
I/O Timings: read=5273.182
-> Parallel Seq Scan on event (cost=0.00..1460292.69 rows=64414 width=157) (actual time=3658.410..4235.849 rows=8 loops=3)
Filter: (index <@ '[30000000,30000025)'::int8range)
Rows Removed by Filter: 10064877
Buffers: shared hit=1236553 read=62777
I/O Timings: read=5273.182
Planning Time: 0.067 ms
Execution Time: 4249.849 ms
```

Finally, our old hack using `upper` and `lower` and splitting it into multiple queries for each range:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, buffers)
SELECT
    id, index, data
FROM
    event
WHERE
    index >= lower('[30000000,30000025)'::int8range) and(upper_inf('[30000000,30000025)'::int8range) OR index < upper('[30000000,30000025)'::int8range));
```

Has the following:

```
Index Scan using idx_event_index_unique on event (cost=0.44..9.37 rows=7 width=157) (actual time=0.016..0.037 rows=25 loops=1)
Index Cond: ((index >= '30000000'::bigint) AND (index < '30000025'::bigint))
Buffers: shared hit=28
Planning:
Buffers: shared hit=8
Planning Time: 0.305 ms
Execution Time: 0.054 ms
```

That is, compared to the first two that use ranges for comparison it is several orders of magnitue faster (0,054ms compared to 4s).

Comment: This is going to need more information 1) An example of the multirange values. 2) The results of `explain(analyze, buffers)` for the query. **ADD to question as text**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the following, I'm using *index_seq* to avoid potential confusion due to using *INDEX* as an identifier instead of a keyword.

Unfortunately, PostgreSQL doesn't use the fact that `x <@ '[l,u)'::int8range` is semantically equivalent to `l <= x < u` and thus doesn't take advantage of the available index. One option is to add an exclude constraint and modify the query to express *index_seq* as a single value range that is checked for inclusion in the multirange:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;

ALTER TABLE events
  ADD CONSTRAINT event_index_seq_exc EXCLUDE USING gist (int8range(index_seq, index_seq, '[]') WITH &&);

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, buffers)
SELECT
    id, index_seq, data
FROM
    event
WHERE
    int8range(index_seq, index_seq, '[]') <@ '{[30000000,30000005],[30000010,30000025)}'::int8multirange;
```